# Find where (item, major_axis, minor_axis) in pandas pandel are specific values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas panel and I don't know how to get it's location (items value, major_axis value, minor_axis value).

Here is my panel:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

items = ['z1', 'z2']
major_axis = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
minor_axis = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']

macierz = np.random.rand(2,3,4)

panel = pd.Panel(macierz, items = items, major_axis = major_axis, minor_axis = minor_axis)
```

I want to find where are values larger than 0.5.

How can I do that?

Comment: Seems like the [pandas.Panel documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html?highlight=panel) has some clear places to start.  What have you tried to augment the code you've posted for your stated need, and where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I can search in one dimension not in three at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Along which dimension?  What is your expected output?

Here is one way to view your desired results:

```
p['z1'][p['z1'] > .5]
          x1        x2        x3        x4
y1  0.911244  0.503100  0.630195       NaN
y2  0.986738       NaN       NaN  0.848044
y3       NaN  0.995088  0.728642       NaN

p['z2'][p['z2'] > .5]
          x1        x2        x3  x4
y1  0.530856       NaN  0.841835 NaN
y2       NaN  0.766699       NaN NaN
y3  0.916617       NaN       NaN NaN
```

Comment: I would like to find x, y, z at the same time so to have a list of points; something like: p[][p[] > .5] = (item=z1, major_axis = y1, minor_axis = x1) ; (item=z1, major_axis = y1, minor_axis = x2) ... and so on....